# Prometheus bind: address already in use

Tags: prometheus, tendermint

I installed prometheus version 2.19 for linux amd64 and when i try to start prometheus, it said bind: address in use. When i used the command './prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml' i got an error bind: address in use 9090. But when i check for pids of process running in 9090, it gives me null. However for the command './prometheus --web.listen.address =:9010 &' i get to see the metrics at localhost/9010 as well as localhost/9000. Now i tried to use it with tendermint, with port 26660. i made change to target in prometheus.yml to include localhost:26660. But again when i start prometheus it gives me the address in use error.